# Javascript Canvas - Functions making all entities disapear

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using javascript canvas to create a little school project.
I have problem with function. After I add it nothing will load.
Like the canvas dont work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="ctx" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;background-image:url('space-1.jpg')"></canvas>


        <script>  
            var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = '30px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

            document.onkeydown = function(event){
                if (event.keyCode === 68 && falcon.x < 600 ) { //d
                    falcon.x += 10;
                    bullet.x +=10;
                } 
                if (event.keyCode === 83 && falcon.y < 360){ //s
                    falcon.y +=10;
                }
                if (event.keyCode === 65 && falcon.x > 0) { //a
                    falcon.x -=10;
                    bullet.x -=10;
                }
                if (event.keyCode === 87 && falcon.y > 0) { //w
                    falcon.y -=10;

                }
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    fire = setInterval(fireBullet,10);
                    if(bullet.x < 0) {
                        bullet.x = falcon.x;
                        clearInterval(fire);
                    }
                }
            }; 

            falcon = {
                x : 10,
                y : 10,
                img : 'falcon1.png'
            };

            bullet = {
                x : falcon.x,
                y : falcon.y+55,
                img : 'bullet.png'
            };

            enemy = {
                x: 0,
                y : 0,
                img : 'enemy_1.png'
            };

            setInterval(update,10);

            function update(){ 
                /* Clear rect*/
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,500);

                /*Draw Falcon and coords*/
                drawEntity(falcon.x, falcon.y, falcon.img);
                ctx.fillText("X : " + falcon.x + " Y : " + falcon.y, 600,480);

                /* Bullet moving with falcon and fire */
                drawEntity(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.img);
                bullet.y = falcon.y+55;

                /* Enemy*/
                drawEntity(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.img);

            }

            function drawEntity(x, y, img){
                var Img = new Image();
                Img.src = img;             
                ctx.drawImage(Img,x, y);
            }

            function fireBullet(){
                bullet.x -=10;

            }  
            function testCollision(entity1, entity2) {
                var distance = getDistace(entity1, entity2);
                return distance < 2;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine but after I add this code and I need it for collision
and I even tried to get the code inside the function to testCollision function and it wont help.

```
    function getDistance(entity1, entity2) {
        var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
        var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
        return Math.Sqrt(vx*vx+*vy*vy);
    }
```

All my entities just dont render I uploaded pictures about it.
BEFORE adding
[image: Before I add getDistance function]

AFTER adding
[image: After I add the code]

Can someone help ?

Comment: Use Math.sqrt instead of Math.Sqrt in getDistance

Comment: Math.sqrt didnt helped, still no rendering

Comment: Then there must be some errors in your console. what does your console print?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * Yeah this line return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+*vy*vy); how can I fix it ? :D Its rendering bad in comments there are * between vx vx and vy vy

Comment: remove * in your equation before vy

Comment: Ok thanks now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function *getDistance* should return this:

```
return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
```

Hope this helps.